# MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 send request - The connection with the server was terminated abnormally - win7

Tags: .net, rest, msxml

I have some code in an ERP system, going through a .Net wrapper calling a REST API.
It is a JSON API.
My code does not make sense to post directly since it is inside the ERP system.
But the code is somewhat like this below.

Strange thing is, that it works on our test/dev site. It works at the customer site on a Win10 PC. But it doesn't work on a Win7 PC. That gives error:
The connection with the server was terminated abnormally 
Errorcode: 0x80020009

It tried to disable all firewall on PC, but without result. Where to look?

Code:
    Dim objXmlHttpMain As Variant
    Dim strJSONToSend As Variant

```
strJSONToSend = "{""Type"":""Push"", ""Push"":{""type"": ""messaging_extension_reply"", ""conversation_iden"": ""<MobileNumber>"", ""message"":""Test""}}"


Set objXmlHttpMain = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

objXmlHttpMain.Open "POST", "https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/ephemerals", False

objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "Access-Token", strAccessToken
objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
objXmlHttpMain.setProxy 2, strProxy
objXmlHttpMain.setProxyCredentials strUser, strPass

objXmlHttpMain.Send strJSONToSend

Debug.Print objXmlHttpMain.responseText
```

Comment: You have to look at the other end of the wire.  If you can't get good support from the company then dump them.

Comment: Hans, as I see it, the error must be in my end. It works on a different site on various PC's. On customer site it doesn't work on one specific PC.